# How to improve performance of GIT operations when GIT local working directory resides on a network share?

Tags: git

Our working environment does not have access to local drive. So the working directory(which also means .git directory) has to be on a mapped network share. I measured the performance of running "git clone" on a network share. It is 60 times slower than running on local drive "C:".

Is there any parameter which I can tune to improve the performance a little bit?

This is for SAS so the folder directory is in SAS environment. I can also see other use cases where local folders are not allowed for security reasons.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what kind of working environment this is ?

Comment: For example : if these environments are only temporary (and you need to, say, clone some repo each time you start such an environment), you could try to mount some form of RAM fs

Comment: When I cut off my feet I can't run very fast, is there some medicine I can take or exercise I can do to run better after I've cut off my feet?

Comment: Well, there are many programmers which work in workstation  or remote server environment which are out of their own control, especially those places totally controlled by IT department. Is there anything we can do to help them using GIT even if they don't have a local drive to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not much you can do in Git itself other than turning on the "don't lstat files" option (`core.ignoreStat`).  Doing so is usually a bad idea because it makes actually *using* Git extraordinarily difficult: *you* have to keep track of any file you've modified.

Your best bet is simply "don't do that".  Git is already a *distributed* version control system.  It really wants to have the entire repository, *and* your working tree, *locally, privately, on an un-shared disk on an un-shared file system*.  Do that.  Do not attempt to subvert it; this will just make both you and Git miserable.<sup>1</sup>  Put a drive (preferably an SSD) on the machine.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Don't anthropomorphize computers.  They hate that!"

Comment: git wouldn't know, but GIt would.

Comment: With GIT being ubiquitous as well as cloud configuration, such demand for GIT will get more popular. Maybe GIT people should start to work on a solution.